# Why is Gohan shown to be so weak in Dragon Ball Super?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-super

Gohan was the strongest in his mystic form back at the end of DBZ. How could Gohan have become so weak that he lost the ability to turn Super Saiyan 2 in such a short period of time? While on the other hand, Frieza was able to surpass Goku's Super Saiyan Blue transformation in only 4 months of training. That doesn't make sense.

Tagoma was even able to pierce him with a ki blast. Now he is losing left and right in every episode. Most recently Frieza in his base form was shooting ki blasts through Super Saiyan Gohan. So Frieza's base form is stronger than Super Saiyan now? How did that happen?

Comment: if your referring to Freeza in Resurrection F remember that he trained so he wouldn't loose to a Super Saiyan again....otherwise it would be kinda pointless for him if he lost again now to an out of date Saiyan form. as for Gohan i got the feeling he no longer regularly trains given that Chichi wanted him to study more and spar less so not to end up like Goku

Comment: Although orange is a good series, but still has a script with several failures :/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> How could be become so weak that cant even go super saiyan 2 anymore in a short period of time

According to the [timeline](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Dragon_Ball_timelin) of dragon ball, about 5 years have passed between the end the buu saga and the Resurection of F saga. Gohan hasn't trained at all since then. We can choose the analogy of professional athletes here: they need to train almost everyday to maintain their form, let alone get "stronger". After 5 years, it is expected than Gohan has become significantly weaker. But again, if he were to train for a few months, his power would probably go up exponentially. Also note that he did not train much in the Buu saga, much of his power increase came from the help of Supreme Kai.

> ...while frieza surpasses goku SSB in 4 months of training

Frieza states that he never had to train one day in his life because he was already so much stronger than everybody else. If we consider Goku to be a combat genius, imagine how much training and near-deaths experience he had to go through to be able to fight on par with Frieza. In the end, only Krilin's death helped become super saiyan and beat Frieza. Since he never trained before, it would make sense that his power would go up exponentially after little training.

> Tagoma was even able to pierce him with a ki blast.

In the movie "Resurrection of F" Goku in Super Saiyan blue was almost killed by a Sorbet's gun. This tells you that no matter how strong of a warrior you are, you can be defeated by someone so much weaker than you if you are caught by surprise.

> So frieza base is stronger than super saiyan now

Yes, when Gohan clearly states than he is no match of Frieza, he is still in his base form. Gohan might be able to sense Frieza's ki beyond his current form, but this is just speculation.

Answer (score 5):

WARNING: THIS ANSWER CONTAINS SPOILERS UP TO EPISODE 23

The amount of time that's passed in Dragon Ball Super is apparently open to interpretation. In BoG, Gohan was probably still the strongest or at least on the same level as Goku before he goes SSJG, hence the reason why they made it a point to have him step in as if he was the only one who could stop Beerus. Obviously, that didn't work out too well for him. But he powered up into his "mystic" form and that's the last time we see it, so far.

I don't see how he could have fallen so far behind Goku and Vegeta prior to their being trained by Whis, but basically Gohan hasn't trained, like at all. Not like the time between when he fought Cell and Majin Buu where he just slacks on his training—this time he really did nothing at all. The most "training" you see him do is when he's play fighting with Mr. Satan as Great Saiyaman over baby Pan.

They do make it a point to show that he hasn't necessarily lost his power, as he's able to easily beat Ginyu (in Tagoma's body) as a Super Saiyan, just the ability to access all of it at will without seriously injuring or killing himself has been lost. Against Frieza, he may have been able to fight with him and at least hold him off till Goku and Vegeta got there, but we all saw what bringing out more power than his body can handle did to him. Think Kaioken and what happened to Goku when he fought Vegeta, except on a much larger scale.

They also made it a point to show that maybe he wasn't necessarily "too weak" to face Frieza, just too soft. He lets his guard down while showing mercy to Ginyu in the same way Goku did with Frieza and pays for it with a ki blast through the shoulder. Given that he was clearly angry with himself for letting his training go, which made him unable to protect his family, maybe he's learned his lesson about just assuming his dad or Vegeta will always be there to protect everyone and will find some motivation to train a little bit. We'll see. My point is that they seem to be putting raw power into a grey area and focusing more on ability, experience and fighting spirit in this series. That's just my opinion based on the fact that Roshi was there fighting when Yamcha is easily at least still stronger than he is. Anyway, I hope that helps anyone wondering what's happening with Gohan. He's not weak, power-wise, he's just out of shape and rocking the dad bod.

Comment: I feel like I must agree with this comment for way too many reasons, but I wanted to comment especially on this last bit. See, I too have noticed that DBS focusses way more on ability, where DBZ focussed on raw power. (Note that in DB, it was all about ability as well. Raw power only mattering in the case of King Piccolo, where the difference was huge). The whole point of SSJB is that it's an advanced form of ki control. They make it seem like 'god ki' is just the ultimate control of ki, meaning it's not a raw power boost, but an efficiency boost. So yeah, agreed.

Answer (score 3):

> Gohan was the strongest in his mystic form back at the end of DBZ. How could Gohan have become so weak that he lost the ability to turn Super Saiyan 2 in such a short period of time? While on the other hand, Frieza was able to surpass Goku's Super Saiyan Blue transformation in only 4 months of training. That doesn't make sense.

The theory acts actually goes like this, Mystic Gohan got his powers without training (Old Ki awakened his powers). After the Kid Buu incident and Berus arrival approximately 5.5 years had passed, Mystic Gohan didn't train for 5 whole years, he didn't even use his KI for that much time. At first he got the power as a given and after that he didn't train so his power drained off in the first place.

> Tagoma was even able to pierce him with a ki blast. Now he is losing left and right in every episode.

Tagoma was even able to pierce him with a ki blast, that was due to his body. He hadn't trained in a while making his body dull, your body needs to be activated with a certain amount of KI to deflect energy blasts.

> Most recently Frieza in his base form was shooting ki blasts through Super Saiyan Gohan. So Frieza's base form is stronger than Super Saiyan now? How did that happen?

Frieza had said that he was born so much powerful so he didn't need to train. Well Goku was weak as compared to Frieza from the very begenning so it could be that training had different results on both of them, may be frieza had this as a natural talent that's why he surpassed Majin-Buu and Mystic Gohan in his base form.